# How to successfully install FIELDimageR package in R4.3.0 despite getting the 'non-zero exit status' warning?

Tags: r

Trying to install FIELDimageR package in R4.3.0. But getting the following error message:

```
> devtools::install_github("OpenDroneMap/FIELDimageR")
Downloading GitHub repo OpenDroneMap/FIELDimageR@HEAD
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\ahasa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUHGCPX\remotes24fc32122835\OpenDroneMap-FIELDimageR-c0a3f92/DESCRIPTION' ...
─  preparing 'FIELDimageR':
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
─  building 'FIELDimageR_0.3.3.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ahasa/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'FIELDimageR' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: object 'elide' is not exported by 'namespace:maptools'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'FIELDimageR'
* removing 'C:/Users/ahasa/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/FIELDimageR'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/ahasa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUHGCPX/file24fc253451f0/FIELDimageR_0.3.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I solve this problem?

Trying to install FIELDimageR package in R4.3.0.

Comment: maptools 1.1-7 deprecates (rather harshly) `elide()` in favor of the `sp` package (version 1.6-2, not yet released). See the diff updating to 1.1-7 [here](https://github.com/cran/maptools/commit/bdfd5d517df267e8d973ccd8dee6d758e679ee3c), noting the `NEWS.md` update and the commenting-out in the `NAMESPACE` file. If you can find the 1.1-6 version of `maptools`, I suggest installing it and then re-attempting installation of `OpenDroneMap/FIELDimageR`.